# Parsing tags with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, parsing, tags, beautifulsoup

I am stuck with a python programming problem regarding BeautifulSoup.

At first, I needed to create a function that would extract all  tags from source page of a webpage. I did this as follows:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    soup=BeautifulSoup(''.join(data))

    def parseUsingSoup(content):
        return soup.findAll('h3')
```

The website I am trying to parse is this one: http://www.auc.nl/news-events/events-and-lectures/events-and-lectures.html?page=1&pageSize=40

It contained only one h3-tag. Now the problem wants me to extend my function such that it will also return all the content related to it within p-tags. It also asks for a list of the event with four tuples that give the date, the title, the type and the description of the event.

I don't really know how to do this. I tried all kinds of different things, but nothing gives me the right results. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way you can get all the `<p>` tags below the `<h3>`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

content = 'http://www.auc.nl/news-events/events-and-lectures/events-and-lectures.html?page=1&pageSize=40'

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(content))

for x in soup.findAll('h3'):
    for y in soup.findAll('p'):
        print y
```

Then you can parse this output into a list as you see fit.

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful. Is there a possibility where I can call the time of the event (and the type, title etc) from the html-code? Such that I can make a dictionary for each event separately (and then later put those in a list)?

Comment: Yes, it seems that you just need to experiment with fetching different tags until you find the right one.  For the second part of your comment, you can save the result to a variable and then parse that variable.  For a more detailed answer, create a new question.