# Some tags are missing while trying get(url)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags

I am able to read all the tags while reading the html of a url manually. But while trying with code I am not able to see all the tags.

I tried

```
url = https://example.com
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url))
```

and

```
response = requests.get(url,proxies=proxies,verify = False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
```

None of them gave me the expected output. I also tried, [BeautifulSoup4 missing tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000770/beautifulsoup4-missing-tags?rq=4), [Unable to parse the HTML in python using beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434404/unable-to-parse-the-html-in-python-using-beautifulsoup?rq=4,)

[Parsing tags with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703256/parsing-tags-with-beautifulsoup?rq=4).

Comment: When using *requests* try printing *response.text* It may not look like what you expected. Can you share the actual URL you're using?

Comment: If the website you are visiting is dynamic and relies heavily on JavaScript to load content, then BeautifulSoup may not be able to capture all the tags as it does not execute JavaScript.

Comment: I tried selenium and webdriver_manager.chrome too.. Other than these libraries what else can be used for this @OmMishra?

Comment: I tried view the html content in postman application. In that also I couldn't see all the tags

Comment: @Amzzz It may be because the website allows it only on a browser. Try adding `User-Agent` header along with your `request.get()`. Code:

`user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3"`

Comment: `headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}`

Comment: `response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)`

Comment: This will mimic like a real web browser.

Comment: Did you check the HTTP status code? If not, why not?

Comment: @DarkKnight yes I checked. There I can see all the tags.

Comment: @OmMishra I tried. Still tags are not visible.

Comment: Please show the actual code you're running. You say you check the HTTP status code but there's no indication of that in the code shown in your question. Also, if response.text contains valid HTML then there's no reason (that I know of) why BeautifulSoup would not be able to process it